# Simulator face id shortcut

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm working with Face ID authentication.

I often have to interact with the options in `Hardware > Enrolled / Matching Face / Non-matching Face` but there is no shortcuts for these actions.

Is anybody knows a tip or how to add a shortcut to the iOS simulator menu ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your own shortcuts in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.

Here is an example of how I am using it:

[image: Example of keyboard shortcut]

Here is a reference: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac